# Barcode detector with Zxing

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I try to implement a barcode scanner. I use zxing library. I have tried qrcode scanning from image, it works.

My decode code is here:

```
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector =
            new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                    .build();

    Frame myFrame = new Frame.Builder()
            .setBitmap(myQRCode)
            .build();

    SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = barcodeDetector.detect(myFrame);
    if(barcodes.size() != 0) {
        Log.d("Data: ", barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
    } else {
        Log.i("QRError", "No QR data");
    }
}
```

Also, I write a code to generate QR code from string. But I can't implement QR scanner from camera source. I know that I can do this task by detecting QR code each frame. But I think that it will be slower than existing solutions. Does zxing has a solution for this? I don't want to use any 3-party library.

Answer (score 1):

This is Zxing official library and it provides the best example for both Barcode reader and generator as well as QR Code reader and generator.

[Zxing Library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

Comment: I add zxing latest release version to my app via `compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'`. But intent guide's example doesn't work for me. The error is `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }`

Comment: Give me a moment, let me create an example for you.

Comment: https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner.
This library uses ZXING as a core. You can take a look at it. Its really light weight. Though I know you wont use 3rd Party

Comment: I don't want to use any 3-party libraries. I expect that there is a way to connect camera source and barcode detector on zxing library. But I can't find it yet. Also, intent example uses zxing barcode scanner apk. It contains many unnecessary ui objects for me.